Embedded JS - property value expected
I was working on a project using embedded JS, and when I try to load a property, it displays the error "property value expected." The code runs perfectly fine, but the error always appears at the beginning.
<label for="<%= user.id %>" style="background-color: <%= user.color %>;">

The error occurs at the beginning and end of this segment: <%= user.color %>.
Error
[{
    "resource": "",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "css-propertyvalueexpected",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "property value expected",
    "source": "css",
    "startLineNumber": 15,
    "startColumn": 60,
    "endLineNumber": 15,
    "endColumn": 61
}]

[{
    "resource": "",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "css-ruleorselectorexpected",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "at-rule or selector expected",
    "source": "css",
    "startLineNumber": 15,
    "startColumn": 78,
    "endLineNumber": 15,
    "endColumn": 79
}]

I attempted to search online, but I was unable to find a solution for this issue. I am looking for an alternative method or solution to eliminate this error.

...is thast error message coming from ESLint or is it a runtime error?

"The code runs perfectly fine" - So does the rendered markup show a value for background-color?

@GreenSaiko Yes, it does load the designated color.

@Dai Yes, it is an ESLint error.

@Thomasantony do you have any plugins/extension installed for ESLint? Because I think ESLint doesn't understand EJS syntax on its own. What's weird though is that it only has an issue with the second ejs part.

@GreenSaiko There is a issue raised about this bug in GJS-grammer repo. https://github.com/Digitalbrainstem/ejs-grammar/issues/93

The issue can be resolved with a simple code modification, although it may not be the most well-structured solution.
Replacing the
style="background-color: <%= user.color %>;"

With
<%- 'style = "background-color: ' %><%= user.color %><%- '"' %>

This will resolve the issue for now, but it may occur again in the future.
The issue has been raised on GitHub; you can check it out as well.
GitHUB issue
